# How to paste a text or code without Enter or Return

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, git-bash

I'm facing a problem when I'm trying to paste a code or text inside the git bash in windows 7 by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>insert</kbd> it is pasting the code but with Enter or return action interfacing!
What I want to do exactly is:

```
$ echo "Code with break lines" >> index.html
```

I want to insert the above code in `index.html` file by using ( echo command ) without opening the editor.

Middle click in mouse also gives the same result

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Terminals usually do that because it fears that the user carelessly copy and paste code from an unknown source which can result to damage on your computer, I would say that you can tweak around the settings in your Git Terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert using the `cat` command in bash with `<<` like this:

```
cat << EOF > index.html
// Insert your copy here
EOF
```

It will catch all, even your line breaks [more information about <<](https://superuser.com/questions/1003760/what-does-eof-do).

The word next to the `<<` means that it will read everything as a user input until it find the specified word in this case `EOF`, but if you want you can use another word.

Comment: It works like a charm Thank you Mauricio
BTW I replaced EOF with simply just a dot "."